# Error 405 on the user registration page on the site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, backend

According to the code below, I set the HttpPost feature to action, but when I hit the registration button on the site, I get a 405 error.
//code
public class Account : Controller
{

```
 private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
 public Account(IUserRepository userRepository)
 {
     _userRepository = userRepository;
    
 }


 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Register(AccountViewModel Register)
 {
     //بررسی موفقیت اتصال
     if(!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return View(Register);
     }
     if (_userRepository.IsExistEmail(Register.Email.ToLower()))
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError(key:"Email", errorMessage:"آدرس ایمیل در سایت ثبت شده است");
         return View(Register);
     };
     User user = new User()
     {
         Email = Register.Email.ToLower(),
         Password = Register.Password,
         isAdmin = false, registerDate = DateTime.Now
     };
     _userRepository.AddUser(user);
     return View("SuccessRegister", Register);
 }
```

I used [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] feature but it didn't fix the problem. I even used the post method in the form in the view, but I encountered this error again.By fixing this error, users can register if they are not admin.

Comment: What URL are you calling? 405 means there's no endpoint matching the request.  Are you POSTing to /Account/Register ?

Comment: endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" Register is an action in the account controller

Answer (score 0):

> According to the code below, I set the HttpPost feature to action, but
> when I hit the registration button on the site, I get a 405 error

Well, based on your scenario and description along with the shared code, it would nicer if you could share your view as well.

Based on my investigation, a `405 error` typically indicates that the HTTP method used for the request is not allowed for the requested resource. In the context of your code, it seems that the issue might be related to how the HTTP POST request is being handled.

In order to deep down your issue, could of stuff you would need to check carefully,

First of all, make sure your *registration form* uses `method="post"` in its opening tag. Also check the  browser developer tools or inspecting the form's HTML source.

Another importnat things is that, verify the form's action attribute points to the correct URL handling the POST request. It should typically be the path to the Register action in your Account controller.

In addition, since you've mentioned using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, ensure that you have the appropriate  tag in your view with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside it. Also, ensure that the token is being submitted along with the POST request. sometimes, [incorrect routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0) could also cause this error.

**Note:** Please follow the above steps carefully. You can also r[efer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages) for more information.